# yeoman generator-aspnet syntax error bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, yeoman-generator, yo

I'm on OSX and I have the following error when I try to launch the following command :

```js
yo aspnet
undefined:6
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3"
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Object.parse (native)
    at EditionInterface.module.exports [as readJSON] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/read-json.js:5:17)
    at Base.determineAppname (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:735:25)
    at Base (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:150:23)
    at new yeoman.generators.Base.extend.constructor (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/app/index.js:9:32)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:282:10)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:259:15)
    at Environment.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:318:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:86:9
    at Environment.resolver.lookup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js:50:12)
```

I'm big noob on npm, so someone can help me and tell me how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the generator is trying to read a JSON file. But that JSON file contains invalid JSON syntax so the generator cannot read it.

Maybe you edited a JSON file with invalid syntax?

If you didn't modified any json file, then you should open an issue on [generator-aspnet](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet).